# Update from address in auto-email reply for cases submitted through portal

Tags: customer-portal, email2case

When a customer creates a new case in our customer portal, our standard web-to-case email template is used to send an auto-reply with general information about the new case.

We use the same email template for auto-replies when customers email our support team directly. The from address in our web2case auto-reply email is our support email that I specified in org-wide emails.

However, when cases are created in the portal, the From address is the customer's email. Any ideas how to update the From address?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the from address is defaulting to the user's address instead of our standard support email, but I solved the problem with a case-auto-response rule.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_auto_response_rules.htm&language=en_US